# Running Shiny app with global file that has a different name

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio-connect

I have one folder with 2 Shiny apps inside - they share `ui.R` and `server.R` but their `global.R` files differ. How to run Shiny app with `global2.R` file instead of `global.R`? I was trying

```
shiny::shinyApp(
  ui = source("ui.R")$value, 
  server = source("server.R")$value, 
  onStart = source("global2.R")
)
```

but it doesn't work.
Not sure if relevant but I'm publishing the app on RStudo Connect.

Comment: For me, this sounds like you have just one shiny app with two different databases. Whats in your `gloabl2.R`?

Comment: It's a bit hackish. Apps have 1 feature different (this is a boolean variable in global.R). But I need 2 dashboards since they are for 2 different groups of people.

Comment: I would use environmental variables and spin two docker containers with the same image containing ui and server instead. You can also just create a file `state.txt` containing either TRUE or FALSE and then do `state <- readLines("state.txt")` in the common global.R.

Comment: ...or even pick up the user's name (`Sys.info()["user"]`?) and decide on the appropriate UI using a lookup table...  It would also be easy to include a button/menu item to allow users to flip between the two UIs (if that is an appropriate thing to do).

Comment: We are using RStudio Connect to deploy our apps so I don't think this is the option.